# How do I find the first # after an even number of "?

Tags: regex, awk, grep, sh, string-matching

Reading a text file with the format:

```
e2c=["(vsim-86)" ,'kkk', "pppp", 
"bbbbbb", #"old", "uio",
" sds # sds", #"old2",
" sds # sds", " a # b",#"old2",
# ' sds # sds',
# - "example of string to override"
 "aaaaaa" ]
```

I'm trying to get the index of the first `#` after 0-N sub-strings using regular expressions but I don't manage to find the correct one.

The string example is `" sds # sds", #"old2",`

The code is:

```bash
while IFS= read -r rline; do
  echo $rline # prints a line from the file
  index=$(grep -P '(^[^\"]*(["][^\"]*["][^\"]*){0,}[^\"]*#)'  <<< "$rline" | awk '{print index($0, "#")-1}')
  echo "The index of the first not in string # is: $index"
done < file.txt
```

And the output:

```
e2c=["(vsim-86)" ,'kkk', "pppp", 
The index of the first not in string # is: 
"bbbbbb", #"old", "uio",
The index of the first not in string # is: 10
" sds # sds", #"old2",
The index of the first not in string # is: 6
" sds # sds", " a # b",#"old2",
The index of the first not in string # is: 6
# ' sds # sds',
The index of the first not in string # is: 0
# - "example of string to override"
The index of the first not in string # is: 0
 "aaaaaa" ]
The index of the first not in string # is:
```

it keeps returning index = 6 instead of 14

if the string was `" sds # sds", " a # b",#"old2",` should be giving 23 but also gives 6.

Comment: Are those double quotes `"` actually part of the string or is that two strings or ??? From your code, it looks like the issue is that you are closing the string too early because of double quotes contained in the string. If that is the case, you need to properly escape the string first.

Comment: @JeffC - Fixed, I forgot to update it
The double quote exist, they come from a text file I'm reading

Comment: You need to update your question to reflect that you are reading strings from a file because your code doesn't indicate that. I think a lot of people are going to notice the same issue I did.

Comment: The title states that you are looking for the first # after an even number of `"`s... I think a different/better way to phrase that is you are looking for the first # outside of matching `"`s.

Comment: Now what's the relationship between the file and `rline`? The `rline` assignment is not doing what you hope; you are assigning the string `aa # bb,` where part of the value is quoted; the rest is a comment.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah... I was trying to get that fixed. :) `rline` is supposed to contain a line from the file so I just updated it myself.

Comment: More generally you want to avoid `while read -r` for this kind of thing.

Comment: Your sample input looks like properly formatted csv.  If you don't have any commas inside of quotes anywhere, the solution is trivial.  Stop thinking about quotes and think about fields that are comma separated.  If you do have commas inside of quotes, the problem is still trivial, but you'll want  a csv parser.

Comment: soooo, you're looking for the index of the first `#` that is not embedded within a pair of double quotes?

Comment: great, you've shown us your current code's output; now what's the (correct) expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `grep | awk` here. Just single `awk` like this would do the job on any awk:

```bash
awk -F '"' '{
s = 0
for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
   if (i%2 && (p = index($i, "#"))) {
      print s+p
      next
   }
   else
      s += length($i)+1
}' file

11
15
24
1
```

PS: These indices start from position `1` as per the awk standard.

This `awk` command splits each line on `"` character and `i%2 != 0` condition makes sure to operate on odd numbered fields only to make sure we are searching for `#` outside the double quoted text.